# Display related data when filtered in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Hello, here is my dataset :

[image]

What I would like to have is a filter on Campagne which shows all the other Campagne if the Contract number is the same. I explain myself. If I click on `Campagne 3` in my filter, I want to see 1, 2, 3 and the `attribution` (the attribution by Campagne, not a Sum). Here is the expected result :

[image]

For now, the only solution that I have is to use a "temporary" table. But it's not optimal because I have to duplicate the data.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to create an extra table or two to get the slicer to work how you want. There's no way around it, but you only need to duplicate part of the data. Here's what I would suggest.

---

Create a new `Slicer` table by summarizing the `Campagne` and `Contrat` columns from your original table.

```
Slicer = SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Campagne], Table1[Contrat])
```

Now since you want the filtering to be done by `Contrat` and this would require a many-to-many relationship with the original table, you need to create a bridge table.

```
Contracts = VALUES(Table1[Contrat])
```

Now set up the relationships on `Contrat` making sure that the `Slicer` to `Contracts` relationship has cross-filtering enabled both ways.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Now you can use the `Slicer[Campagne]` column for your slicer and put `Table1[Campagne]` on your table and it should filter how you want.

[image: Result]